# Process C# does not return anything

Tags: c#, asp.net, command-line, process

I'am working with Process, and it has strange behavior. I need to execute code with Process my WebSections.exe program. Interesting thing, when i pass wrong parameters, it show result that it wrong, when i pass correct parameters it does not show anything, like it would not execute anything at all.
So parameters for my program is WebSections.exe f (.xml file).
But if i call with same parameters as in the code but straight out of command-line, it works.

And also i commented the .ExitCode, bacuse it shows: "System.Exception: Program returned with error code 2 at simplepage.". But with it commented it seems to be working.

```
        Process p;

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

        psi.FileName = "C:\\inetpub\\WebSections\\Program\\WebSections.exe";

        psi.Arguments = "f  C:\\Users\\HrchM\\Desktop\\Program\\Current_Diagram\\diagramResult.xml";

        psi.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\inetpub\\WebSections\\TempFolder";

        psi.UseShellExecute = false;

        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

        p = Process.Start(psi);

        try
        {
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            p.WaitForExit(60000);

            /* if (p.ExitCode != 0)// returns 255 when it can’t write to the temp folder (C:\inetpub\WebSections, CZ-CRM\IIS_IUSRS, Modify, replace all child objects)
                throw new Exception("Program returned with error code " + p.ExitCode); */



            ViewData["Content"] = output.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewData["Content"] =  ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            p.Close();
            p.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-system-error-codes-exit-codes-description `2`: *The system cannot find the file specified.* As far as I see, you are using ASP.NET MVC, that means, hosted in IIS. If it is a legitimate IIS, and not the development instance, it will run as a service, and your code runs under the application pool identity. So: are you sure the apppool identity has all the file system permissions to execute this process with all the files it should use?

Comment: I am sure, i use the same program (WebSections.exe) but with another parameters in the app and it works fine.

Comment: You say: *with other parameters*. Than it means that the problem is related to **these** parameters. Beware: you are passing a file path to a user's desktop. That's unreachable even to the administrators unless explicitly granted. Just as a trial: copy that file to a path like `c:\temp` where everyone can reach it, make sure that it is readable (and writable if needed by your app) by everyone and try it from there.

Comment: Hm... it seems that i have a problem with my .xml file. I have an .xml example and it works with this example file, but not working with dynamically created file. I do not understand what the difference between them. And funniest thing, that my dynamically created file works if i call WebSections.exe straight out of CMD, but not through C# Process....

Comment: Try starting a cmd in the name of the app pool identity - and/or add logging to the `WebSections.exe` if it is your code.

Comment: You mean call cmd instead of WebSections.exe? Well, now it has infinite loading..

Comment: No. Just to see how the WebSections.exe works under the identity it will actually need to work in, start a cmd under the identity of the app pool you are using in IIS for your application and execute the same command you have already ran from cmd. This time would run not under your identity, but under the app pool's.

Comment: Sorry if i dont understand you clearly, or explain.. You want me to call cmd with Process and pass there my WebSections.exe?

Comment: No!!! Option1: `runas` https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html Option2: search for `cmd.exe` in start menu, right click on it, select _Run as different user_, provide app pool user credentials. Then execute your WebSections.exe.

Comment: I found what was the problem, it did not like my path inside the xml... I'm soryy for being stupid :( And really thank you for your help.